# Dealing with large Blackberry applications (lots of pictures)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have a blackberry application with lots of images that was build for pre-OS7 handsets. I have to make it up to date with the **new screen sizes**, and my 5Mb app will be almost twice as big, which means over the limit for it to work.

**What is the best way to handle that in the BB Java Plug-in for Eclipse** ?

I've come to the conclusion that i have 2 choices :

- Including the new images as a cod (or is it jar?) library in my current project, but didn't manage to do that. Most of what i read was for the JDE anyway and i'd like to do that in Eclipse.
- Have a second Bundle for new handsets, but how to do that without having 2 different projects ?

Downloading the new images on install seems to be another one, but it's not an option for this project.

Details and/or links appreciated, as i'm quite new to BB development.

Many thanks

Comment: In BB, there are so many different screen sizes, that your approach of custom images was flawed from the beginning. Now either scale or compress the existing ones, or try to use another approach (tiling and backgrounds, or SVG if available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view the better way is to use only the biggest possible images in the project and scale them down proportionally for every device **at the runtime**.

When you scale down an image its quality {almost} does not change. There are exceptions, sure. But in general this rule works.

Also you may use [preprocessor](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#preproc) to build different cod files for different devices with different screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep bigger images and get rid of smaller ones. You can handle devices that has lower resolution via image scaling. This way your application becomes smaller.

Answer (score 1):

According to me i suggest you that you have to make same app for only `Blackberry OS 7.0` because it has different different resolution and if you manager your application for all `Blackberry OS` than your app will become `larger size` and it may be possibilities that we cant upload our app in `Blackberry app world`.

Remove all previous OS graphic and put into for only `Blackberry OS 7` and upload it on market so OS 7.0 user download the latest app.